# assigning variable from dataframe pyspark

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I am naive in Pyspark and please pardon for silly question.

I have a data frame which contains three field, id, Name, Address and have five rows.
I have to loop through the data frame and call function on them.

However I am not able to assign variable value from each column.

Reading the file (which is working fine)

```
file = "dbfs:/mnt/s3_path/data/file.csv"
data = spark.read.format("csv").option('inferSchema', 'true').load(file) \
              .withColumnRenamed("_c0", "id") \
              .withColumnRenamed("_c1", "name") \
              .withColumnRenamed("_c2", "add")
```

Trying to assign the variable which is not working

```
for loop in data:
    id = loop.id
    name = loop.name
    add = loop.add
    function_call(id)
```

The function is never getting id. instead when printing the id it is showing 
Column

Any suggestion.

Comment: you are trying to call function for each value of id. In that case, you can use UDF,where UDF will be your function.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your function to user-defined function, to convert your python function to udf visit this [blog](https://changhsinlee.com/pyspark-udf/).

Another way is you can collect the result and pass it to your python function like this but this is least recommended as it brings all your data to driver and then there is no point of using spark.

```
for loop in data.collect():
    id = loop.id
    name = loop.name
    add = loop.add
    function_call(id)
```

I would suggest, you go through some basic action and transformation for better understanding [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html)